# Is there any way to force web clients to use a secure SSL cipher (TLS 1.1/TC4) in my C# Web Server, to avoid BEAST attacks

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-4.5, beast

I have a specialist web app written in C# - my C# code acts as a web server, accepts connections from browsers, and presents the app as web pages.

The existing app uses SSL to secure the connection from the browser, but I am concerned about BEAST, which renders many of the older SSL ciphers insecure. I therefore want to ensure that I only accept connections using TLS1.1 or later, and/or secure cyphers like RC4.

I have already accepted that I will have to ditch the SSL library I was using, and probably switch to .NET 4.5 with SslStream.

Although I see how I can check the cypher for a stream using SslProtocol and CipherAlgorithm, I cannot find a way to force a connection to prefer one of the more secure algorithms. Am I missing something?

For the avoidance of doubt, this is nothing to do with ASP - this server is written in raw C#. I need a programatic way of making SslStream prefer particular ciphers. It is unlikely that I will have the necessary permissions to alter ssl registry settings on the host server.

Comment: You can throw an exception if SslProtocol or CipherStrength do not match a specified criteria and force the connection to close using TcpClient's Close() method

Comment: Don't worry too much about BEAST. It's only applicable if you mix trusted and untrusted code, and up-to-date implementations are not vulnerable even with CBC suites.

Comment: But SSL+.net is not a nice combination. MS's `SslStream` doesn't allow sufficient control over the suites. Mono only supports weak suites[other people disagree, perhaps you like on of them]. BouncyCastle is great, but client only. OpenSSL-net has[or had, I tried a year ago] some bugs and didn't look confidence inspiring. GnuTLS has no .net wrapper, but a nice c API.

Comment: It is not me that is worried about BEAST, but the user. No amount of reassurance from me will stop them insisting! Looks like I will just have to reject less secure protocols, and just hope that the net library will choose a secure protocol if one is available.